# How do I use AutoMapper with Ninject.Web.Mvc?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, automapper

### Setup

I have an `AutoMapperConfiguration` static class that sets up the AutoMapper mappings:

```
static class AutoMapperConfiguration()
{
    internal static void SetupMappings()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<long, Category>.ConvertUsing<IdToEntityConverter<Category>>();
    }
}
```

where `IdToEntityConverter<T>` is a custom `ITypeConverter` that looks like this:

```
class IdToEntityConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<long, T> where T : Entity
{
    private readonly IRepository _repo;

    public IdToEntityConverter(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public T Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _repo.GetSingle<T>(context.SourceValue);
    }
}
```

`IdToEntityConverter` takes an `IRepository` in its constructor in order to convert an ID back to the actual entity by hitting up the database. Notice how it doesn't have a default constructor.

In my ASP.NET's `Global.asax`, this is what I have for `OnApplicationStarted()` and `CreateKernel()`:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    // stuff that's required by MVC
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    // our setup stuff
    AutoMapperConfiguration.SetupMappings();
}

protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<NHibRepository>();

    return kernel;
}
```

So `OnApplicationCreated()` will call `AutoMapperConfiguration.SetupMappings()` to set up the mappings and `CreateKernel()` will bind an instance of `NHibRepository` to the `IRepository` interface.

### Problem

Whenever I run this code and try to get AutoMapper to convert a category ID back to a category entity, I get an `AutoMapperMappingException` that says no default constructor exists on `IdToEntityConverter`.

### Attempts

1. Added a default constructor to `IdToEntityConverter`. Now I get a `NullReferenceException`, which indicates to me that the injection isn't working.
2. Made the private `_repo` field into a public property and added the `[Inject]` attribute. Still getting `NullReferenceException`.
3. Added the `[Inject]` attribute on the constructor that takes an `IRepository`. Still getting `NullReferenceException`.
4. Thinking that perhaps Ninject can't intercept the `AutoMapperConfiguration.SetupMappings()` call in `OnApplicationStarted()`, I moved it to something that I know is injecting correctly, one of my controllers, like so:

   ```
   public class RepositoryController : Controller
   {
       static RepositoryController()
       {
           AutoMapperConfiguration.SetupMappings();
       }
   }
   ```

   Still getting `NullReferenceException`.

### Question

My question is, how do I get Ninject to inject an `IRepository` into `IdToEntityConverter`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to give AutoMapper access to the DI container. We use StructureMap, but I guess the below should work with any DI.

We use this (in one of our Bootstrapper tasks)...

```
    private IContainer _container; //Structuremap container

    Mapper.Initialize(map =>
    {
        map.ConstructServicesUsing(_container.GetInstance);
        map.AddProfile<MyMapperProfile>();
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

@ozczecho's answer is spot-on, but I'm posting the Ninject version of the code because it has one little caveat that caught us for a while:

```
IKernel kernel = null; // Make sure your kernel is initialized here

Mapper.Initialize(map =>
{
    map.ConstructServicesUsing(t => kernel.Get(t));
});
```

You can't just pass in `kernel.Get` to `map.ConstructServicesUsing` because that method has a `params` parameter in addition to the Type. But since params are optional, you can just create the lambda expression to generate an anonymous function to get you what you need.

Comment: how to initialized `kernel`?